# Spark/Scala update the value of a variable in another map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

In Spark, I have a

```
closest: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (breeze.linalg.Vector[Double], Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[476] at map at command-1043253026161724:1
```

I want to  calculate some total distance:

```
var tempDist=0.0
closest.foreach(x=> tempDist=tempDist+squaredDistance(x._2._1, kPoints(x._1)))
```

But this doesn't change `tempDist`'s value at all. I suspect Spark doesn't do anything. So how can I calculate the distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do mutable vars. It's a bad idea in general, and doesn't work at all with spark, at least, not the way you are doing it, because it's a distributed system. 
Different partitions of the sequence are located on different computers, and are being processed independently in parallel and *in different JVMs*, each of which has its own copy of the `var`.

```
  val tempDist = closest
    .map { x => squaredDistance(x._2._1, kPoints(x._1) }
    .fold(0) { _ + _ }
```